# View is blank even though Firebug sees HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

My master page looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/CSS/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Mobile.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p>Hello from Mobile Land</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Firebug shows this as the HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ui-mobile ui-mobile-rendering landscape ui-loading min-width-320px min-width-480px min-width-768px min-width-1024px"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"><base href="http://localhost:2189/Home/MobileHome"><link href="../Content/CSS/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>
    Test    </title></head>
<body>
    <div>

    <p>Hello from Mobile Land</p>

    </div>


</body></html>
```

So I'm trying to figure out why I can't see anything on the screen?

Comment: I take it you're using jQuery mobile? What are you viewing the website on? PC, mobile device etc? jQuery mobile uses Ajax to display a lot of the content, have you checked any Ajax requests that are being made and what's being returned?

Comment: I assume the meta, base, and link tags are being closed correctly, and that firebug is omiting the /> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery mobile requires all HTML markup to be contained within `data-role` attributes, otherwise it won't render them.

The anatomy of a Mobile page is something like this:

```
<div  data-role="page"> 
    <div  data-role="header">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="content">...</div> 
    <div  data-role="footer">...</div> 
</div>
```

If you put your `<p>` tag within something like the above, it will work. That's just how JQuery mobile builds the page. If you include the Mobile scripts, it's going to try and do this every time.